# htaccess handle subdomain and remaining traffic

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I know there is a flurry of other questions on here regarding this topic, but I was unable to use them to conquer my problem.

Here is what I am trying to do: We had a domain change, we moved a site from its own domain to a subdmain:

www.oldsite.com -> http://oldsite.newdomain.com

There was also an old subdomain:

http://sub.oldsite.com  which needs to be http://sub.newdomain.com

I was trying to handle this in htaccess by first catching if there was the subdomain and redirecting it, if it did not, simply redirect the rest of the traffic.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

#Send all traffic to store.newsite.com
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^store.oldsite.com [NC,OR]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://store.newsite.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

#Sends all traffic to store.newsite.com
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^store.oldsite.com$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://store.newsite.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]

#Doesn't catch the sub domain and all redirects fall to the 301
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  store.oldsite.com$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://store.newsite.com/$1 [P] 

#redirects all traffic, but not additional pages   e.g.  newsite.com/a/b/c
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite.com [NC,OR]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.oldsite.com [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

</IfModule>

#redirects all traffic and the additonal params  /a/b/c
Redirect 301 / http://newsite.com/
```

I tried all of these individually while leaving the 301 redirect at the bottom in case any of the rules were not met. The comment above the code block tells what result I received. I am not highly versed with htaccess and could use any help I can get. Thanks in advance.

What I expect:

```
 store.oldsite.com => store.newsite.com   (this is the only sub domain)

 oldsite.com    =>  newsite.com    (All existing pages, could be up to 4/5 deep.   e.g.    oldsite.com/a/b/c/d  => newsite.com/a/b/c/d)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    #Redirect old store to new domain
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^store\.oldsite\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://store.newsite.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

    #redirect old site (with or without www) to new domain
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.|)oldsite\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

    #redirect others to new domain homepage
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} oldsite\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ http://newsite.com/? [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I was waiting until the edit completed. Thanks again!